# Finding file on mobile device after successful phonegap download

Tags: android, cordova, download, file-transfer

I'm using phonegap and I've successfully implemented fileTransfer.download or at least I think I have.  I am downloading a file named SOBRITE.PDF to a directory that I successfully created named "my_downloads".  The fileTransfer.download success function executes and says I've successfully downloaded my file to "my_downloads\SOBRITE.PDF"

So my problem is after I've supposedly successfully downloaded my file, I don't know how to find it on my Android device.  My package name is com.highbrookcreate.wf3 and I try to find the file I've downloaded at:

```
file:///data/data/com.highbrookcreate.wf3/my_downloads/SOBRITE.PDF
```

but I get a

```
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error
```

Where is the "my_downloads" folder and where is my file??

A bonus answer would also tell me where this file and folder are on an iOS device!

Comment: i can find the file on an iOS device by using the following URI:

cdvfile://localhost/persistent/my_downloads/SOBRITE.PDF

but the question remains for Android

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct URI for a downloaded file on Android.

It is

```
file:///data/data/com.highbrookcreate.wf3/files/files/my_downloads/sobrite.pdf
```

where "com.highbrookcreate.wf3" is my package
      "my_downloads" is the folder to store downloads
      "sobrite.pdf" is the filename of the downloaded file